# AWS X-Ray causes my app to throw a NullReferenceException from ASP.NET MVC code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

In my ASP.NET MVC app running on EC2, I get the following exception when accessing my webapp:

> [NullReferenceException]: Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetNotifcationContextProperties(Boolean&
>   isReentry, Int32& eventCount)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)    at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)

As you can see, the error is in the .NET framework, not thrown directly from my Global.asax.cs.
Here is my Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        AWSXRayASPNET.RegisterXRay(this, "authorize-qa");
    }
}
```

I've confirmed the X-Ray Windows Service is running on my instance.

Comment: Docs/samples for XRAY seem to utilize the `Init()` method of `HttpApplication` rather the `Application_Start()` event.  Have you tried it this way?  https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet

Comment: @DavidTansey I saw that before I saw your answer and I just tried it. It works. Thanks for your answer, feel free to submit it as an official answer so I can mark it as such!